# Why is the company name in the DocuSign user profile not reflected in recipient email?

Tags: docusignapi

Why isn't the Company name in the User profile reflected in the email that is sent to the signature recipient?  Seems like the "Account Name" always shows up in the email as the Users company name regardless of the value set in the User Profile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is to make use of DocuSign custom account branding.  You can control the look and content of things like the signing experience, email notifications, and other aspects.  Have a look at the account branding guide:

[DocuSign Custom Account Branding](http://www.docusign.com/sites/default/files/Quick%20Start%20-%20Account%20Branding.pdf)